# Only run function on element click with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I would expect this function to only run when clicking on a `<a data-popup="true"></a>` element however it's running on every `<a>` click.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').data('popup', 'true').click(function(e) {
            console.log($(this).data('popup'));
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.data()` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) get/sets data associated with the element; it doesn't filter the elements like you are expecting. You are actually setting a key/value pair of data on all the anchor elements and then attaching an event listener to all the anchor elements. In other words, when you set data with the `.data()` method, the original jQuery object is returned (which means that the `.click()` method is still attaching a click event handler to all the originally selected anchor elements).

You are looking for an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). In this case, the selector `a[data-popup="true"]` will select anchor elements with a `data-popup` attribute value of `true`.

```
$('a[data-popup="true"]').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data('popup'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will attach data for all existing a link in the code.

```
$('a').data('popup', 'true').click(function(e)
```

you may try this:

```
<a id="popid" data-popup="true"></a>

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#popid').click(function(e) {
            console.log($(this).data('popup'));
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

To check popup for all a link, you may try below.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            if ($(this).data('popup')){
                console.log($(this).data('popup'));
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
$('a[data-popup="true"]').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data('popup'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```